# How to display images in custom listview with transparent backgrounds

Tags: android, listview

I want to display images with transparent background in the custom listview

This is my xml code

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" >

</ListView>
```

This is my List Item code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This is my .java code

```
ListView list;
String[] web = {
        "  Profile",
        "  Help And Support",
        "  Account Settings",
        "  Location Settings",
        "  Notifications",
} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.profile2,
        R.drawable.help,
        R.drawable.account,
        R.drawable.location,
        R.drawable.notification,

};
    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(settings.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(settings.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Kindly help me out. How to set transparent background color of images only.

Comment: where is your `CustomList` code and list item xml code ?

Comment: Please check whether the images you are using have transparent background or not

Comment: pls add your output screenshot and also customList Adapter for more details.

Comment: I have added custom list adapter in the .java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, background of the imageview should be transparent. that's the difference of the imageview compare to imagebutton. make sure you're using the setImageResource and not the setBackground in the getView() method of your custom adapter. and of course if your image drawable itself has background, you have to remove it using any photo editing software. i normally upload png images that has transparent background

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```